# Add an error in ValidationSummary programmatically in data-ajax-success call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm displaying, with success, a `ValidationSummary` containing the errors that the `jQuery` unobstrusive validator detects :

```
<form asp-controller="PlanningYearsEditModal" asp-action="EditPlanningYear" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onSuccess">
    <div id="content" class="modal-body">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <table class="inner" style="width:100%" border=1>
            <tr class="azurbox rounded3 white bold">
                <td style="width:20%">@CommonResources.CommonField</td>
                <td style="width:80%">@CommonResources.CommonValue</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="underline">
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LabelFr)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LabelFr)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LabelFr, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="underline">
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LabelNl)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LabelNl)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LabelNl, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Save changes</button>
        <div id="Results"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

After these simple checks, I have to do manual integrity checks in my controller, who returns a `JSON` containing the errors. I would like to use the validator to be able to display these errors in the ValidationSummary. I could probably update the html code with `jQuery` manually, but it causes a lot of issues (sometimes the validation summary already exists, sometimes not, sometimes you just have to replace a few bullets, sometimes not, ...).

I feel like there is probably a way to do this in a clean way.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't display anything on screen (and I can confirm that is code is being called) :

```
var onSuccess = function (errors) {
    var errorArray = {};
    errorArray["LabelFr"] = 'Some error thrown by the controller';
    $('#myForm').validate().showErrors(errorArray);
};
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Not sure why you think adding the `<li>` elements for you additional errors is an issue (and the `<div>` and `<ul>` elements generated by `@Html.ValidationSummary()` always exist)

Comment: I don't think so, when there are no errors, there is a div whose class is validation-summary-valid text-danger, and that is then replaced by a class named -danger validation-summary-errors where there is an error that the jquery unobstrusive validatiob detects.

Comment: If you return errors, you get the element using `$('[data-valmsg-summary]')`, set the class to `"validation-summary-errors"` and simply `.append()` the messages in a `<li>` - just a few lines of code

Comment: `var vs = $('[data-valmsg-summary]'); $.each(errorArray, function(index, item) { vs.children('ul').append($('<li></li>').text(item));
}); if (errorArray.length > 0) {vs.addClass('validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-valid');}`

Comment: It's starting to look better, but I still have an issue, the errors are not reset after each submit, which means that if my controller returns 2 errors, and that I click on "submit" 3 times, 6 errors will be displayed (these errors will be cleared if it's the unobstructive validator that return an error).

Comment: vs.children('ul').empty(); seem to do the trick though. Would you have done it that way ?

Comment: Use something like `.append($('<li class="custom"></li>')` in the code above, so that way you can remove any that you added previously (I assume that is what your mean)

Comment: Everything works, thank you so much !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use mvc's client side validatiion, the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plug-in parses the document and configures the `$.validator` in `jquery.validate.js`. You should not attempt to modify the `$.validator` or call `validate()`.

Your `@Html.ValidationSummary()` generates a `<div>` (with a `[data-valmsg-summary]` attribute) which contains a `<ul>` element. To add the messages, you can simply add `<li>` elements containing the error message

```
var vs = $('[data-valmsg-summary]'); // get the div
if (errorArray.length > 0) {
    // update class name
    vs.addClass('validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-valid');
}
$.each(errorArray, function(index, item) {
    // add each error
    vs.children('ul').append($('<li></li>').text(item));
});
```

If this is being called multiple times, and you do not want to display previously added errors, you can give the `<li>` elements a class name, say

```
vs.children('ul').append($('<li class="myerror"></li>').text(item));
```

and then remove them using `vs.find('.myerror').remove();`